# Seq is already in use/consumed (nested gather / take )

Tags: raku

```
sub f()
{
    gather
    {
        take gather { take 3; take 4; take 5; }
        take gather { take 1; take 2; take 3; }
    }
}

say f.sort
```

blows with

```
The iterator of this Seq is already in use/consumed by another Seq
(you might solve this by adding .cache on usages of the Seq, or
by assigning the Seq into an array)
  in block <unit> at so.raku line 1
```

Whereas

```
sub f()
{
    gather
    {
        take cache gather { take 3; take 4; take 5; }
        take cache gather { take 1; take 2; take 3; }
    }
}

say f.sort
```

Works as expected and produces `((1, 2 ,3), (3, 4, 5))`. That's fine (thanks raiph). Now

```
sub MAIN( *@n )
{
    @n = @n || ( 3, 4, 5, -1, 111, 27, 28, 29, 1, 2 );

    chunks( @n, { $^left < $^right } )
        .sort({ [*] |$_ })
        .tail
        .say;
}

sub chunks( Iterable $list, &condition )
{
    my $windows = $list.rotor( 2 => -1, :partial ).iterator;
    my $done    = False;

    gather until $done
    {
        my Mu $window := $windows.pull-one;

        last if $window =:= IterationEnd;

        take cache gather
        {
            my $condition-result;

            while $window := $window // $windows.pull-one
            {
                $done = True and last if $window =:= IterationEnd;

                take $window[0];

                $condition-result = &condition( |$window )
                    if $window.elems == 2;

                $window := Any;
                last unless $condition-result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This should produce `(27 28 29)`, but it doesn't. It produces  `(111)`. But when I replace `take cache gather` by `take eager gather` it works as expected.

my `chunks` function has the same structure than the simpler example above, I reckon and yet there seems to be a difference in the behaviour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Total rewrite**

There are three plausible scenarios.

In all of them, `take eager gather` is the solution instead of `take gather`.

This leaves the outermost `gather`.

You can leave it as is. This means if you bound the result of the `chunks` call to a variable, and then did two iterating operations on it, you'd get the `Seq is already in use/consumed` error.

Or you can deal with that problem. You have two options, depending on whether you prefer the `chunks` operation to be eager or lazy. If you want it to be eager, then write the outer `gather` as `eager gather`. If you want it to be lazy, write it as `cache gather`.

Answer (score 6):

The problem seems to be in your `take gather` construct. It puts (still open) `Seq`s inside your big outer `Seq`. I "fixed" your code by substituting `take gather` by `take my @x = gather` and everything worked as you wish, I think.

Comment: (yes, I could have converted the internal `Seq` to `List` or `Array` in many other ways...)

Comment: Saying ` take eager gather` does it as well and keeps the list character, but thank you for pointing me into the right direction